# Swift 5 delete section from CollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, delete-row

i am trying to make ability for user to delete message from chat, i am using MessageKit which section based collectionView lib. I am trying to delete section by long press. What am i do wrong?

I'm getting this error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 0
>   from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update'

**long press**

```
@objc func longPressed(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
        let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.messagesCollectionView)
        if let indexPath = messagesCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: touchPoint){
            //indexPath.row = 0
            //indexPath.section = 1
            //row always is 0, and section +1 for every next message
            messageList.remove(at: indexPath.section)
            collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
                collectionView.reloadData()
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}


func numberOfSections(in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> Int {
    return messageList.count
}

func messageForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> MessageType {
    return messageList[indexPath.section]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this :

```
if let indexPath = messagesCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: touchPoint){
        //indexPath.row = 0
        //indexPath.section = 1
        //row always is 0, and section +1 for every next message
        messageList.remove(at: indexPath.section)
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

Just reload the collection view after removing the message from the array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it gives me *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 0 from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update'